# Building a QT Designer Layout including a variable-sized widget

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a class that contains a viewer (a custom QLabel that displays Pixmaps) and buttons beneath it to scroll through the images available (which are of different sizes).

I want the buttons to appear immediately beneath the image, which means they need to move everytime the image changes. However, when load a bigger image, it just covers over the buttons. How do I set it up in QT designer to avoid that? I thought that putting the viewer and the buttons into a QVBoxLayout would be enough, but when the QLabel resizes, the size of the layout as a whole does not. I've tried playing around with size policies for quite a while, but I must be failing to understand something.

Edit - Here is my attempt at showing just the minimal code required and the UI file.

```
from sprite_viewer_ui import Ui_SpriteViewer

class SpriteViewer(QWidget, Ui_SpriteViewer):

    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(SpriteViewer,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.session = Session()

        self.sv = SpriteLabel(self.session,parent=self)
        self.setupSession(self)

    def setupSession(self):
        #Update the slider and spinbox with the new range
        self.spriteSlider.setRange(1,self.session.getNumSprites())
        self.spritePicker.setRange(1,self.session.getNumSprites())

        #Show the initial sprite
        self.sv.showSprite(1)
        self.spriteSlider.setValue(1)

        #Make connections
        self.spriteSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.session.setSprite)
        self.session.spriteChanged.connect(self.sv.showSprite)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = QApplication(sys.argv)

    se = SpriteViewer()
    se.show()

    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

So the code here just uses the UI to build a basic interface with a viewer `sv` and a spinbox and slider to show which sprite is used. The ui file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>SpriteViewer</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="SpriteViewer">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>658</width>
    <height>420</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <property name="sizeConstraint">
    <enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
   </property>
   <item>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="sv">
     <property name="minimumSize">
      <size>
       <width>640</width>
       <height>360</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QSlider" name="spriteSlider">
       <property name="maximum">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="tickPosition">
        <enum>QSlider::TicksBelow</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="tickInterval">
        <number>30</number>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QSpinBox" name="spritePicker">
       <property name="maximum">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>spriteSlider</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>spritePicker</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>562</x>
     <y>361</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>587</x>
     <y>362</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>spritePicker</sender>
   <signal>valueChanged(int)</signal>
   <receiver>spriteSlider</receiver>
   <slot>setValue(int)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>594</x>
     <y>361</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>540</x>
     <y>363</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

I realize that is a nightmare to read. But basically it's a spinbox and a slider in a QHBoxLayout, and a QLabel (which I later set to my SpriteViewer class, which subclasses QLabel. This one is the problem - every sprite is a different size, and I want SpriteViewer to resize according to the size of SpriteLabel.

Comment: This is pretty much impossible to answer without seeing the .ui file (plus any code that might be directly relevant).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to upload a minimal case as soon as I can. I was hoping there was some easy answer like calling some layout.update() type thing when the sizes of the internal widgets have changed.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem - just following up so the question isn't left incomplete.

I had failed to understand how promoted widgets work in QT Designer, so on this line:

```
self.sv = SpriteLabel(self.session,parent=self)
```

I had assigned self.sv to a completely new SpriteLabel (which was not part of the layout) and so resizing it had no effect on the layout. Instead I had to use the "Promote to" context menu in Designer to indicate it was a SpriteLabel, and then leave the assignment up to the UI file.